# AngularJS and JS Math.max.apply() not working together

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am going through a code example in a book on learning AngularJS, and something is not working as the book shows it does. Opening up the html page in both Chrome and Firefox have no problem with the angular expressions until the last one. Any ideas to get that last mustache to show the right thing??

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.Math = window.Math;
    $scope.myArr = [];
    $scope.removedArr = [];
  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Expressions</title>
    <style>
      a{color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <h1>Expressions</h1>
      Array:<br>
        {{myArr}}<hr>
      Elements removed from array:<br>
        {{removedArr}}<hr> 
      <a ng-click="myArr.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*100 + 1))">
        Click to append a value to the array</a><hr> 
      <a ng-click="removedArr.push(myArr.shift())">
        Click to remove the first value from the array</a><hr>
      Size of Array:<br>
        {{myArr.length}}<hr>
      Max number removed from the array:<br>
        {{Math.max.apply(Math, removedArr)}}<hr>   
 </div>  
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/expressions_javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't directly access `Math` object method on scope, unless controller ha in `$scope.Math = Math`,do call a function from `interpolation` {{}}, and the do `Math.*` calculation over the controller side. like `{{calculate(removedArr)}}`

Comment: If I change {{Math.max.apply(...)}} to {{Math.max(1,2,3)}} it works fine. So I'm not sure what you said applies in this situation.

Comment: Don't put that sort of logic in the view...it belongs in your controller

Comment: @charlietfl I'm just trying to understand the book's example, as I am new to Angular...

Comment: For security reasons, you can't invoke the `apply` function in an angular expression. See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-40

Comment: @dnc253 thank you. my book was written in 2014 so I have to assume that they just didn't care/know about this change for this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @dnc253 for giving the simple reason why it was not working, and to @charlietfl for the best solution. Here is my newbie way of making this work.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.Math = window.Math;
    $scope.myArr = [];
    $scope.removedArr = [];
    $scope.maxNumm;
    
    $scope.maxNummm = function()
    {
     $scope.maxNumm = Math.max.apply(Math, $scope.removedArr);
     console.log("maxNumm: " + $scope.maxNumm);
    };
    
  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Expressions</title>
    <style>
      a{color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <h1>Expressions</h1>
      Array:<br>
        {{myArr}}<hr>
      Elements removed from array:<br>
        {{removedArr}}<hr> 
      <a ng-click="myArr.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*100 + 1))">
        Click to append a value to the array</a><hr> 
      <a ng-click="removedArr.push(myArr.shift()); maxNummm();">
        Click to remove the first value from the array</a><hr>
      Size of Array:<br>
        {{myArr.length}}<hr>
      Max number removed from the array:<br>
      <!-- For security reasons, you can no longer invoke the
       apply function in an angular expression -->
        <!-- {{Math.max.apply(Math, removedArr)}} -->
        {{maxNumm}}
        <hr> 
 </div>  
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/expressions_javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
enter code here
```